# Gestetner Printer - access to stapling option from .Net

Tags: .net, printing

I there any possibility to access specific printer option(stapling) from .Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a printer driver and PrinterSettings, then you might want to take a look at this:

[Programmatically selecting complex printer options in C#](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2008/11/programmatically-selecting-complex-printer-options-in-c-shar/)

or

[Serialize Printer Settings](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/printersettings.aspx)

My guess is that these settings are in PJL so the alternative is to produce your own PCL/PS for the job and then simply insert the PJL at the top of the file.  You can then send using:

[How to send raw data to a printer by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)